# Interpretation of: $a\mid c \wedge b\mid c \wedge (a,b) =d \Rightarrow ab\mid cd$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am not sure of the significance, but had a curiosity and hence placed the below question. Idea is may be it sheds some more insight from the community.

Interpretation of: $a\mid c \wedge b\mid c \wedge (a,b) =d \implies ab\mid cd$

It is easy to prove the above, but the significance of the same is difficult to interpret for me.

My interpretation is in following parts:

i) $a$ divides $c$, or any prime factor of $a$ divides $c$; and similarly for $b$.

ii) gcd of $a$ and $b$ is $d$. $d$ is the smallest linear combination and the highest common divisor of $a$ and $b$. It also means that $d$ be comprised of $\ge 1$ prime factor(s) and their power(s) $\ge 1$.

iii) If $a$ and $b$ are disjoint, then they are either co-prime or not. If co-prime then, $c$ has at least two different prime factors. Otherwise, $c$ must have at least one prime factor, which should be $d$.

Comment: @OmG How to have formatting in title is not known to me, sorry if off-topic!

Comment: Just using $ as you use in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $c=ax$ and $c=by$. Since $gcd(a,b)=d$ we have $a=da'$ and $b=db'$ where $a'$ and $b'$ are relatively prime. Thus $b'dy = a'dx$ so $a'|b'y$ and since $a',b'$ are relatively prime, by Euclid lemma we have $a'|y$ so $y=a'z$ and now we have
$$ c= ba'z\;\;/\cdot d\;\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;\;dc = ba'dz = baz \;\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;\;ab\mid cd$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, lot. I also request elaboration of "/." symbol. Have encountered on this site many times, but not in a book. Is it a standard notation?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way of thinking about this is that the lowest common multiple of $a$ and $b$ is $\frac{ab}{(a,b)}$. So if $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ then $\frac{ab}{(a,b)}\bigm| c$ and this is equivalent to what you have.